# SQL Server - optimise the stored procedure by using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update all of my calendar start and end date with the UTC dates. I also have to consider the daylight saving dates so I created a temp table and inserted all the daylight saving dates for last 10 years. But I am not sure how can I use the temp table values in my update statement. The code written so far in SP:

```
CREATE TABLE #DTSDates (
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate datetime
);

INSERT INTO #DTSDates VALUES('2011-03-13 02:00:00.000', '2011-11-06 02:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO #DTSDates VALUES('2012-03-11 02:00:00.000', '2012-11-04 02:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO #DTSDates VALUES('2013-03-10 02:00:00.000', '2013-11-03 02:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO #DTSDates VALUES('2014-03-09 02:00:00.000', '2014-11-02 02:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO #DTSDates VALUES('2015-03-08 02:00:00.000', '2015-11-01 02:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO #DTSDates VALUES('2016-03-13 02:00:00.000', '2016-11-06 02:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO #DTSDates VALUES('2017-03-12 02:00:00.000', '2017-11-05 02:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO #DTSDates VALUES('2018-03-11 02:00:00.000', '2018-11-04 02:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO #DTSDates VALUES('2019-03-10 02:00:00.000', '2019-11-03 02:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO #DTSDates VALUES('2020-03-08 02:00:00.000', '2020-11-01 02:00:00.000');


UPDATE Calendar
SET StartDate = CASE   
                    WHEN (StartDate BETWEEN '2011-03-13 02:00:00.000' and '2011-11-06 02:00:00.000') 
                    OR (StartDate BETWEEN '2012-03-11 02:00:00.000' and '2012-11-04 02:00:00.000')
                    OR (StartDate BETWEEN '2013-03-10 02:00:00.000' and '2013-11-03 02:00:00.000')
                    OR (StartDate BETWEEN '2014-03-09 02:00:00.000' and '2014-11-02 02:00:00.000')
                    OR (StartDate BETWEEN '2015-03-08 02:00:00.000' and '2015-11-01 02:00:00.000')
                    OR (StartDate BETWEEN '2016-03-13 02:00:00.000' and '2016-11-06 02:00:00.000')
                    OR (StartDate BETWEEN '2017-03-12 02:00:00.000' and '2017-11-05 02:00:00.000')
                    OR (StartDate BETWEEN '2018-03-11 02:00:00.000' and '2018-11-04 02:00:00.000')
                    OR (StartDate BETWEEN '2019-03-10 02:00:00.000' and '2019-11-03 02:00:00.000')
                    OR (StartDate BETWEEN '2020-03-08 02:00:00.000' and '2020-11-02 02:00:00.000')
                THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, @Offset + 60, StartDate)               
                ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, @Offset, StartDate) END,       
EndDate = CASE   
                WHEN (EndDate BETWEEN '2011-03-13 02:00:00.000' and '2011-11-06 02:00:00.000') 
                OR (EndDate BETWEEN '2012-03-11 02:00:00.000' and '2012-11-04 02:00:00.000')
                OR (EndDate BETWEEN '2013-03-10 02:00:00.000' and '2013-11-03 02:00:00.000')
                OR (EndDate BETWEEN '2014-03-09 02:00:00.000' and '2014-11-02 02:00:00.000')
                OR (EndDate BETWEEN '2015-03-08 02:00:00.000' and '2015-11-01 02:00:00.000')
                OR (EndDate BETWEEN '2016-03-13 02:00:00.000' and '2016-11-06 02:00:00.000')
                OR (EndDate BETWEEN '2017-03-12 02:00:00.000' and '2017-11-05 02:00:00.000')
                OR (EndDate BETWEEN '2018-03-11 02:00:00.000' and '2018-11-04 02:00:00.000')
                OR (EndDate BETWEEN '2019-03-10 02:00:00.000' and '2019-11-03 02:00:00.000')
                OR (EndDate BETWEEN '2020-03-08 02:00:00.000' and '2020-11-02 02:00:00.000')
            THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, @Offset + 60, EndDate)             
            ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, @Offset, EndDate) END  
WHERE CalendarId IN (1,3,4,7,90,34,56,78,23) -- too many ids
```

I have a large number of data and I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it. Can someone suggest how can I optimize the update statement, please advise.

Comment: Can't you do this using `AT TIME ZONE`?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks for the link. Can you please explain this with my code. My server is in US and the clients are based in different locations and if it takes the server time to get the timezone then this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Once you created the temporary table ,
query will be like

```
Update Calendar
Set StartDate = DATEADD(MINUTE, @Offset + 60, StartDate) ,endate= xyz
From Calendar  cal
Join #dtsdates dts
on cal.startdate >= dts.startdate and cal.startdate <=dts.enddate 
WHERE exists (Select id from #selected_id sel where sel.id = cal.id )
```

For the else condition in case

```
Update Calendar
Set StartDate = DATEADD(MINUTE, @Offset , StartDate) ,endate= xyz
From Calendar  cal
Join #dtsdates dts
on cal.startdate <= dts.startdate and cal.startdate >=dts.enddate 
WHERE exists (Select id from #selected_id sel where sel.id = cal.id )
```

IN clause in where should be avoided and it must be replaced by a exists clause. Put these hard coded ids into a temporary table #selected_id and use a exists clause, will improve performance.

If the data is huge, try running these update in batches (using a while loop and a transaction)